# Can I find the smallest vertex cover

Tags: algorithms, decision-problem, vertex-cover

so this is my question:-
If I manage to find a vertex cover which has ....let's say 100 more vertex than the minimum vertex cover. Can I find the minimum vertex cover in polynomial time from this vertex cover?
Here, vertex cover is general vertex cover for any random graph.
Thank you.

Comment: If $k$ is the size of a minimum vertex cover, then you can always find a vertex cover of size at most $2k$ using an approximation algorithm (which adds all vertices in a maximal matching).  However, if P $\neq$ NP, no poly-time algorithm can guarantee finding a vertex cover of size $7k/6$ or less - so there's a limit on what can be done in polynomial time (also, no algorithm can do better than $2k$ if the unique games conjecture is true).  See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000007000864

Comment: If you could do that then you'd immediately have a PTAS for vertex-cover, which is known no to exist (in fact, vertex cover is APX-hard). Enumerate subsets of vertices of size at most $100/\varepsilon$ (they are at most  $\frac{100}{\varepsilon} n^{100/\varepsilon}$). If any of these is a vertex cover, then you have also examined a minimum vertex cover. Otherwise, the minimum vertex cover has $k > 100/\varepsilon$ vertices and $k+100 < (1+\varepsilon)k$, hence your $100$-additive polynomial-time approximation algorithm returns a $(1+\varepsilon)$-approximate vertex cover.